# Spring AMQP Headers are returned as String only

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, message, amqp

I am using Java Spring with version 2.0.0 Snapshot of AMQP. I create an AMQP message, send it. In another service I am receiving the message correctly, except the headers instead of receiving type Object, every header is of type String.

Publisher Code:

```
Message responseMessage = MessageBuilder
    .withBody(SerializationUtils.serialize(person))
    .setContentType(MessageProperties.CONTENT_TYPE_SERIALIZED_OBJECT)
    .setHeader("STUDENT_TYPE", "New") // Not part of person object but related
    .setHeader("PET", getPet()) // This is a pet object
    .build();
rabbitTemplate.send(responseMessage);
```

Consumer Code:

```
Object messageBody = SerializationUtils.deserialize(amqpMessage.getBody());
Person person = (Person)messageBody;
MessageProperties properties = amqpMessage.getMessageProperties();
String type = properties.getHeaders().get("STUDENT_TYPE").toString();
Pet pet = (Pet)properties.getHeaders().get("PET");
```

When I run the above code, I will fail on the last line of the consumer code with the error: Cannot cast String to Pet. The message comes across ok, except every header is of type String when received in the consumer code.

```
USAGE: MessageBuilder.setHeader(String Key, Object Value);

USAGE: Properties.getHeaders() returns Map<String,Object>
```

Every header has key/value pair of type String/Object. The work around I have in place is also serializing an header I would like to pass non-string/integer values for, but this seems to be besides the point of the header. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to serialize your Pet to a string, and deserialize it when you get it in another service. E.g. you can use fasterxml Jackson and serialize it to JSON string

Comment: Where is it explicitly saying my "String" is really a pet? I am populating a header. A header is simply a Map Entry. This map entry, this key value pair, is of type - KEY is the STRING, and the VALUE is OBJECT. -- <String Key, Object Value>, headers.put("MyNewPet", myDog); -- But on the other side when i pull out of the headers, suddenly the Map is now <String Key, String Value> - what happened to the object?

Comment: I guess that's because amqp does not serialize your your object to bytes, most likely it just calls toString() and passes string through broker. As far as I know these queues pass only strings

Answer (score 0):

You are telling the compiler your `String` is really a Pet. However, `Pet` is not a [subclass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) of `String`. There are two possible solutions:

Solution1: You make sure `Pet extends String`, like this:

```
public class Pet extends String {
    //...
}
```

and then you will be able to cast `String` into `Pet`.

Solution2: You implement a constructor of `Pet` which takes a `String` as parameter:

```
public class Pet {
    //...
    Public Pet(String name) {
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Where is it explicitly saying my "String" is really a pet? I am populating a header. A header is simply a Map Entry. This map entry, this key value pair, is of type - KEY is the STRING, and the VALUE is OBJECT. -- <String Key, Object Value>, headers.put("MyNewPet", myDog); -- But on the other side when i pull out of the headers, suddenly the Map is now <String Key, String Value> - what happened to the object?